# EditText ellipsize (three dots...)

Tags: android, forms, android-edittext, longtext

Unfortunatelly I am not able to make ellipsize for EditText works. Is even possible to put three dots at the end of the text when the text is too long? It is working perfectly for TextiView but not for EditText. Some idea?

```
 android:id="@+id/ed_email_personalInfo"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="55dp"
 android:background="@color/transparent"
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:ems="10"
 android:hint="@string/email"
 android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
 android:maxLength="64"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:paddingRight="10dp"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textColorHint="@color/col9a9a9a"
 android:textSize="15.7sp"
```

Comment: recently I faced the same problem, so I developed this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75064128/2578331) which works as expected (adding ellipses) on Android versions starting from API 23 (Android Marshmallow).

Answer (score 23):

**Set this property to edit text.
Elipsize is working with disable edit text**

```
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:editable="false"
```

Comment: It works. And there is no need to set scrollHorizontally and lines properties.

Comment: android:editable property is deprecated and Google recommends to use android:inputType. However, according to my test, it would not work any more if there exists android:inputType

Answer (score 23):

You have to remove `android:inputType` attribute.

**Ellipsize doesn't work if inputType is defined.**

Comment: Perfect, following attributes with the above answer worked - 
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:editable="false"

Comment: This answer does not work. It is also ridiculous if it did because why would Android show ellipsis based on the input type?

Comment: @Mitch undocumented feature b̶u̶g̶ in Android?

Comment: This is the key answer to those who can't ellipsize an EditText despite setting all relevant properties. Once you set `inputType`, it overrides the `ellipsize` property. Moreover, the default behaviour of a single-line EditText is that you can scroll horizontally when the text doesn't fit in the view.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure it answers the question (and I guess the original asker is not so interested anymore, after 7 and a half years), but I'm pretty confident my answer will come in handy to anyone stumbling into ellipsis issues with EditText.

Don't try to find any logic in this, but based on the answers from Oleksandr and Mubarak, I figured out the following:

To ellipsize an EditText in XML, use deprecated `android:editable="false"`. In my case:

```
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

No need to mess with `android:inputType="none"` for the moment. The EditText looks just like a TextView and is properly ellipsized.

It is possible to make the EditText editable (and remove the ellipsis) like this:

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setActivated(true);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS); // or whatever fits your needs
editText.setSingleLine(true);
editText.setEllipsize(null);
editText.requestFocus();
```

Your can then restore the EditText to its original state (ie. disguised as a TextView and properly ellipsized) like this:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
editText.setActivated(false);
editText.setSingleLine(true);
editText.setKeyListener(null); // this is the key
editText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

Answer (score 3):

Might not be possible in EditText (unless you create your own View). I think the default behavior (for singleLine EditText) is that you can scroll the text sideways when it can't fit in the view.

Answer (score 0):

EditText is subclass of TextView, you can override edittext method to make it work like textview
I try this and it work

```
class CustomTextInputEditTextView: TextInputEditText {
constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?): super(context, attributeSet) {

}

override fun getDefaultEditable(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun getDefaultMovementMethod(): MovementMethod? {
    return null
}
```

}

```
<com.CustomTextInputEditTextView
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to overlay the EditText view with an ellipsizable, non-transparent TextView containing the same text. When you tap the TextView, it hides the TextView overlay and passes the click event to the EditText. On completion, refresh the TextView with the new text and make it visible (and ellipsized) again.

Answer (score -3):

You need write a new class that extends `EditText`. for example:

```
MyEditTextEllipsize extends EditText{

private String dotsString;

private String storeString;

public MyEditTextEllipsize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

@Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

         if(focused)

     {
       setText(storeString);
      }else {
             String NOW = getText().toString();
                storeString = NOW;
            if (NOW != null && getWidth() <= getTextSize() * NOW.length()) {

                    dotsString = NOW.substring(0, (int) (getWidth() / getTextSize())) + "...";

                    setText(dotsString);

                }
}

    }
}
```