# scrollHorizontally in edittext don't work

Tags: android, android-edittext

Why `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` don't work?

```
<EditText   
     ...
     android:cursorVisible="false"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:hint="@string/place_search_hint"
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoFullscreen"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
     android:digits="0123456789.,-"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

But if set `android:inputType="text"` - this work perfectly...

Comment: try using singleLine="true" ...Hope this will help you

Comment: @AnamicaBisht don't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If remove `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` in `XML`, and write programmaticaly `placeSearch.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);` in `Java`.

Scroll Horizontally in `EditText` *work perfectly*!

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **ellipsize** attribute. It has no effect as long as you have the **inputType** defined (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276320/edittext-ellipsize-three-dots)) - but could affect the scrolling behavior.

Also, you could try to set the scroll programatically, like `editText.setScroller(new Scroller(myContext));`